# Group rows of data based on a column value

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

Is it possible to group rows based on a value within the subarray?

**Array**

```
Array (
[4f5hfgb] => Array (
[0] => ACME
[1] => 4f5hfgb
[2] => Aberdeen
)
[sdf4ws] => Array (
[0] => ACME
[1] => sdf4ws
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[dfgdfg54] => Array (
[0] => EDNON
[1] => dfgdfg54
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[345bfg] => Array (
[0] => EDNON
[1] => 345bfg
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[345fgfd] => Array (
[0] => VALVE
[1] => 345fgfd
[2] => Birmingham 
)
)
```

Is it possible to chunk those with the same value in `[0]`?

**Desired output**

```
Array (
    [4f5hfgb] => Array (
    [0] => ACME
    [1] => 4f5hfgb
    [2] => Aberdeen
    )
    [sdf4ws] => Array (
    [0] => ACME
    [1] => sdf4ws
    [2] => Birmingham 
    )
)

Array (
    [dfgdfg54] => Array (
    [0] => EDNON
    [1] => dfgdfg54
    [2] => Birmingham 
    )
    [345bfg] => Array (
    [0] => EDNON
    [1] => 345bfg
    [2] => Birmingham 
    )
)

Array (
    [345fgfd] => Array (
    [0] => VALVE
    [1] => 345fgfd
    [2] => Birmingham 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to group all elements that have the same value for key `0` into the same array. You can't do this with `array_chunk` but the loop below produces the grouped array

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v[0]][$k] = $v;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: @serakfalcon in this case i prefer `foreach`

Comment: yeah after a couple minutes thinking about it I see why.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$values = array_unique(array_map(
    function ($v) { return $v[0]; },
    $array
));

$result = array();
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $result[] = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($val) {
        return $v[0] == $val;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `array_chunk` splits array to chunks based on size. You may consider looping through into the array and chunk it into your desired  structure.