# insert in to multi dimensional array in php for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Below given is my array structure

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 59
        [product_name] => Samsung Champ DUOS E2652 
        [product_price] => 4439
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => samsung-champ-duos-e2652---1414801404364308.jpg
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 195
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0
        [product_price] => 17847
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => galaxy-tab-4-7-0---1715601405057269.png
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 284
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite 7.0
        [product_price] => 18000
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => galaxy-tab-3-lite-7-0---1590061405576878.png
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 19
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy Star
        [product_price] => 4833
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => feature-img144811404109906.jpg
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 186
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy S5 Active
        [product_price] => 31922
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => galaxy-s5-active368091404989896.png
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )

)
```

i would like to **sort this array** based on `sub_cat_url` like below

```
array
(
[0] => samsung
   [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 186
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy S5 Active
        [product_price] => 31922
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => galaxy-s5-active368091404989896.png
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 284
        [product_name] => Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite 7.0
        [product_price] => 18000
        [sub_cat_name] => Samsung
        [sub_cat_url] => samsung
        [image] => galaxy-tab-3-lite-7-0---1590061405576878.png
        [currency] => &#x20B9;
    )
)
```

for thet I wrote a code like below.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
            if($i == 0){
                $search_array[$i] = $search_data[$i]["sub_cat_name"];
                $search_array[$i] = $search_data[$i]["product_name"];
                $j += 1;
            }
            else if($search_data[$i]["sub_cat_url"] !== $search_data[$i]["sub_cat_url"]){
                $search_array[$i] = array($search_data[$i]["sub_cat_name"]);
                $search_array[$i] = array($search_data[$i]["product_name"]);
                $j += 1;
            }
            else if($search_data[$i]["sub_cat_url"] === $search_data[$i]["sub_cat_url"]){
                $search_array[$i] = array($search_data[$i]["product_name"]);
                $j += 1;
            }
        }
```

but it didn't work well. And I tried using inner for loop also. It too didn't give me the actual result. Can some one please hlp me to write the correct loop statement for this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to get products filtered by sub_cat_url field ?

Comment: yeah..exactly..sorry...forget to add in question..will edit now

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724430/php-array-chunk-split-based-on-variable

Comment: Can't you get it directly from database by passing your subcategory ? Or you still need it by coding

Comment: I need it by coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well this should work:

```
$out = array();

$map = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   $url = $v['sub_cat_url'];

   if (!isset($map[$url])) {
     $map[$url] = count($out);
   }
   $out[$map[$url]][$url][$k] = $v; // or $out[$map[$url]][$url][] = $v;

}
```

However I haven't tested it (you haven't provided data in PHP format)

Comment: thank you very much for the help...It works 100% as i expected... :)